# VB Lambda that checks for DBNull

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

This code is supposed to return all the records where the month component of the DateCreated is equal to the specified MonthIssued value.  The problem is, if DateCreated is DBNull I will get a runtime exception which requires the extra If ternary operator.  Any way around this / will this cause a performance hit the code is actually executed?

```
resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(d) If(d.a.DateCreated.HasValue, If(d.a.DateCreated.Value.Month = MonthIssued, True, False), False))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using ternaries, try using the short-circuiting `AndAlso` logical operator:

```
resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(d) _
    d.a.DateCreated.HasValue AndAlso _
    d.a.DateCreated.Value.Month = MonthIssued)
```